# How to delete a word in file which is store in internal storage of device in Android

Tags: android

I created a file name with `mydata`.Now iwant to delete some word not fully file only some words. How can i do this anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

**Found a way to delete line in a file:**

> args[0] is the filename
>
> args[1] is the target line number (1-based: first line is #1)

```
public class RemoveLine {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // Use a random access file
    RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(args[0], "rw");
    int counter = 0, target = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    long offset = 0, length = 0;

    while (file.readLine() != null) {
        counter++;
        if (counter == target)
            break; // Found target line's offset
        offset = file.getFilePointer();
    }

    length = file.getFilePointer() - offset;

    if (target > counter) {
        file.close();
        throw new IOException("No such line!");
    }

    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int read = -1; // will store byte reads from file.read()
    while ((read = file.read(buffer)) > -1){
        file.seek(file.getFilePointer() - read - length);
        file.write(buffer, 0, read);
        file.seek(file.getFilePointer() + length);
    }
    file.setLength(file.length() - length); //truncate by length
    file.close();
}
}
```

**Use it to delete words, phrases in your file!**

Link here : http://pastebin.com/MpMKeKik

Comment: what is the value of`args[0]  args[1]`.